# Wordpress: List 'in-common' categories from multiple custom post types that share the same taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently working on a job site in Wordpress that has three custom post types:

```
- Jobs
- Applications
- Resumes
```

When an employer posts a new job, they pick out their desired skills for the job from a custom taxonomy I created called `Skills`.

This taxonomy is shared between the `Jobs` and `Resumes` post types, so they have the same ID and names.

When a candidate signs up, they fill out a resume form and choose their `Skills` from the shared taxonomy. They can submit this resume as an application to a job, which gets stored in the `Applications` custom post type.

I would like to be able to show a message to both the user and employer if the skills on the resume match the skills on the job listing.

E.g.

On **job-single.php**, the user sees:
*"This job matches your skills: Skill 1, Skill 2, Skill 3"*

On **job-application-single.php**, the employer sees: *"This applicant has skills that match this job: Skill 1, Skill 2, Skill 3"*

I have gotten as far as being able to retrieve the taxonomies for both `Resumes` and `Jobs`, but how can I find matching `Skills` between the two post types and display them?

Answer (score 1):

[WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) provides numerous functions for common tasks within The Loop.

The post type parameters show posts associated with certain type.

The taxonomy parameters show posts associated with certain taxonomy.

Within the `single-jobs.php` you would use [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) to retrieve the terms of the current post and run a custom query to retrieve

```
<?php

$terms = get_the_terms(
    $post = get_the_ID(),
    $taxonomy = 'Skills',
);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Skills',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $terms,
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$found_posts = $query->found_posts;

if ( $found_posts ) :

    echo 'This job matches your skills: ' . $terms;

endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

Same approach goes for the rest.